# What does boolean do under these circumstances?

Tags: java

```
public static boolean containsAll(String[] strings, String test)
    {
        if (test == null || strings.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (String str : strings)
            if (!test.contains(str))
                return false;
        return true;
}
```

I have no idea what I can add to a boolean inside the parentheses but I have this line of function in my script with help from a fellow SOF member.

Thing is, how do I know what to write in a parenthesis to declare stuff? I don't know the rules from my memory and I don't have any source I can relate to. Basically I have no idea why there is an array and a string declared in the parentheses.

Basically,

1) Why is there a line declaring an array and a string inside the parentheses?
2) Where can I relate to as a source to get more information about classes like "boolean" and what I can do to change their functions? Basically I want a book-like website I can relate to whenever I don't know about something in java.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: can you explain what you mean????

Comment: This `boolean` is the type returned by this method. It is nothing you 'write'.

Comment: `boolean` does what its supposed to do, in all circumstances!

Comment: Also, there is no `boolean` inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there a line declaring an array and a string inside the parentheses?

So that you can use those parameters within the method , to achieve something .

From the method declaration it seems :

```
public static boolean containsAll(String[] strings, String test)
```

The method tries to search for a String passed as parameter `test` within an array passed as parameter `strings` and returns boolean `true` or `false` depending on whether the `strings` array contains the `test` String or not. Or probably , the method was named `containsAll()` to signify that it ascertain whether all the elements of `strings` array contains `test` string !

**EDITED:** The method checks if all the elements of the strings array contains the test String.

> Where can I relate to as a source to get more information about classes like "boolean" and what I can do to change their functions

[boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is primitive , [Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) is a wrapper class. Your method returns `boolean` primitive.

Comment: So It doesn't change the function of the boolean but rather adds a string and array to use within the statement?

Comment: With just the declaration in hand, we cannot say what the method does . What we can say is that the method takes two arguments `String[]` and `String` and returns the caller a `boolean`.

Comment: This is the full code: too ambiguous, check original post please

Comment: It checks if all the elements of the `strings` array contains the `test` String.